# How to read MonadReader and ask definition?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out, how to read the following class type definition:

```
Prelude Data.Functor.Identity Control.Monad.Reader> :i ask
class Monad m => MonadReader r (m :: * -> *) | m -> r where
  ask :: m r
  ...
```

`m` is a higher kinded type and it has to be a `monad`.

But what does `m -> r` means?

Trying to play a bit with `ask` as the following:

```
Prelude Data.Functor.Identity Control.Monad.Reader> ask "Hello"
"Hello"
```

Why can I pass an argument to `ask`? Looking at the type signature:

```
ask :: m r
```

I can not recognize, that I can pass an argument to `ask`.

Comment: I *think* the idea is that when you attempt to call `ask` on a `String`, type inference allows `m` to be unified with the function monad, so that you end up with `ask :: String -> String`.

Comment: `m -> r` is a functional dependency; knowing `m` is enough to infer what `r` is. In essence, it says that you can't define multiple `MonadReader` instances for the same monad but with different `r`s.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to put a detailed answer, but in short: `m -> r` is a [Functional dependency](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies). And functions are a Monad instance itself, so that's the Monad that Haskell picks when you do `ask "Hello"`. (In fact, this is just the Reader Monad itself.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `m -> r` is a functional dependency, which roughly states that when trying to choose an instance of `MonadReader` to use, knowing `m` is sufficient for knowing `r`. Put another way, you can't define two separate instances with the same `m` but different `r`.

Now, to determine which definition of `ask` to use, we turn to type inference. From its definition, we know `ask` has type `MonadReader r m => m r`. From its use in `ask "Hello"`, we know it also has to have a type like `a -> b`; more specifically, we know that `a` unifies with `String`, since that's the type of `"Hello"`. So our task is to unify `MonadReader r m => m r` with `String -> b`.

This is pretty straightforward. Rewriting `String -> b` in prefix notation and using explicit parentheses , we can line them up together:

```
MonadReader r m => m             r
                   ((->) String) b
```

So `m ~ ((->) String)` and `r ~ b` (though we still don't know what `r/b` should be). Looking at the available instances of `MonadReader`, we find the (unique) instance for `m ~ (->) String` (or more generally, `(->) r`):

```
instance MonadReader r ((->) r) where
    ask       = id
    local f m = m . f
```

So now we know that for our choice of `m`, `ask = id`. (This lets us see that `r ~ b ~ String` as well.)

And so, `ask "Hello" == id "Hello" == "Hello"`.

Note that `ask` doesn't necessarily have to be a function. It might also be a value of type `Reader r a`, in which case `runReader` has to be used to extract the function.

```
> :t runReader ask
runReader ask :: a -> a
> runReader ask "Hello"
"Hello"
```

It might also be a more complicated monad involving `ReaderT`:

```
> :t runReaderT ask
runReaderT ask :: Monad m => a -> m a
> runReaderT ask "Hello" :: Maybe String
Just "Hello"
> runReaderT ask "Hello" :: Either String String
Right "Hello"
```

Comment: I also do not understand `ask :: MonadReader r m => m r` type signature. Why is the type signature include `=>`? What does it mean?

Comment: It means `ask` is value of type `m r` for any monad `m` and type `r` for which there is a `MonadReader` instance.

Comment: Does it mean, the monad instance of type `r`?

Comment: No, `r` is the type "wrapped" by the monad `m`. For the most part, instances of `MonadReader` are (loosely speaking) either functions, `Reader` (itself just a wrapper around a function), or monads built using `ReaderT`. This means that `ask` is almost always a value that is, or from which can be extracted, a function.